# How to avoid repetitive implicit rules in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I am working on a Makefile auto-generating software ([CodeMate](http://dongli.github.com/CodeMate)), and I would like to know if I can avoid to write the implicit rules for different file suffices but with the same operations as:

```
%.o: %.F90
    @echo " Creating dependency $@"
    @echo $(seperator)
    @$(FORTRAN_COMPILER) -c $< $(OPTION) $(FORTRAN_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES)
%.o: %.f90
    @echo " Creating dependency $@"
    @echo $(seperator)
    @$(FORTRAN_COMPILER) -c $< $(OPTION) $(FORTRAN_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES)
%.o: %.F
    @echo " Creating dependency $@"
    @echo $(seperator)
    @$(FORTRAN_COMPILER) -c $< $(OPTION) $(FORTRAN_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES)
%.o: %.f
    @echo " Creating dependency $@"
    @echo $(seperator)
    @$(FORTRAN_COMPILER) -c $< $(OPTION) $(FORTRAN_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES)
```

This can work well, but is a little ugly.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Make are you using? (Try `make -v`.)

Comment: GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Untested:)

```
define f_rule
%.o: %.$(1)
    @echo " Creating dependency $$@"
    @echo $(seperator)
    @$(FORTRAN_COMPILER) -c $$< $(OPTION) $(FORTRAN_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES)
endef

F_EXTENSIONS := F90 f90 F f
$(foreach ext, $(F_EXTENSIONS), $(eval $(call f_rule,$(ext))))
```

Comment: Can you explain how it fails?

Comment: Make complains "*** No rule to make target `main.o', needed by `main'.  Stop.". I have used "$(warning "$(1)")" to check if the argument is ok, and it prints " F90" with a leading space. I don't if this is the problem.

Comment: Break the problem down; verify that `main.F90` exists, then instead of `$(foreach...)`, try `$(eval $(call f_rule,F90))`. If that fails, try `$(info $(call f_rule,F90))` and tell us what it says.

Comment: Wonderful! It is my fault, I have added a space between "f_rule" and "$(ext)". Now it works fine! Thanks!

Comment: I am used to add space among arguments.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the pitfalls of the `call` function. I'm glad you solved it.